# Is a collision attack possible on MD5 if message is known partially

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5

Is it possible to find $m'$ such that $\operatorname{MD5}(m'||m_1)=\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m_2)$ if I know $m_2$ and $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m_2)$? Is this a collision or a preimage attack?

Also in this case is it possible to find $m'$ and $H$ such that $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m')=H$ if I know $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m_2)$ and $m_2$?

Basically a message like $(M,\operatorname{MD5}(M||m1))$ is sent from server to client (only client and server know $m_1$). So is there an attack in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m_2)$ and you know $m_2$, and want to find $m'$ such that $\operatorname{MD5}(m'||m_2)$ reaches a known, predetermined value, then you must break MD5's preimage resistance, or at least second-preimage resistance.

This would be true even if you knew $m_1$: if you know $m_1$, then the problem becomes: find $m'$ such that $\operatorname{MD5}(m'||x) = y$ for two given values of $x$ and $y$ ($x = m_1$ and $y = \operatorname{MD5}(m'||m_2))$ in your presentation). Since $y$ is the result of MD5 on a known entry, this problem is a second-preimage attack with an extra constraint on the result. MD5 is still quite robust against second-preimage attacks, so this cannot be done with existing knowledge and technology.

Not knowing $m_1$ cannot help: if the problem is already hard with knowledge of $m_1$, then it cannot be easier without knowledge of $m_1$.

The explanation above is the general case. In some cases it can be quite easy: for instance, if $m_2$ happens to be equal to $z||m_1$ for some value $z$, then $m' = m_1||z$ would be a solution.

---

If you have $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m_2)$ and you know $m_2$, then you can trivially compute $\operatorname{MD5}(m_1||m')$ for any $m'$ which begins with $m_2$, followed by the MD padding, followed by arbitrary contents. This requires knowledge of the length of $m_1$ (but not its contents). For details, look up the [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

Answer (score -1):

md5 is a one-way hashing function remember? Which means:

```
cipher = md5(plain)
```

If you know `cipher` you cannot possibly get `plain` by reversing md5. Which means:

```
plain != md5(cipher)
```

So s it possible to find `m3` such that `md5(m3+m1)=md5(m1+m2)` if I know `m2` and `md5(m1+m2)`

The answer is absolutely **not possible**. Why you asking?
Simple because if you know `md5(m1+m2)` and `m2` it doesn't mean you know `m1` or `m3` which is the collusion value of m1 in your case.

This not to be confused with symmetric keys encryption, where this scenario is very possible!

If your encryption key for a `session-1` is `K1` and encryption key for `session-2` is `K2` and so on.. It is possible to retrieve plain text if you **REUSE** the key twice as follow:

```
cipher1 = plain1 XOR K1
cipher2 = plain2 XOR K1
```

now XOR both ciphers and see what happens:

```
cipher1 XOR cipher2 = (plain1 XOR K1) XOR (plain2 XOR K1)
```

Notice how `K1 XOR K1 = 0...0000` which makes our `cipher = plain1 xOR plain2` which leads to plain text retrieval by guessing one value and trying to figure our the second.